# I can't start new activity from onListItemClick inside ListFragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-listfragment

I  am not sure what i am doing wrong, so far was working perfectly.Once i wanted to add new activity when item/note is selected to start a new activity it won't work nor gives me an error.

This is ListFragment

```
public class ListFragmentMain extends ListFragment {

private ArrayList<Note> notes;
private NotesAdapter notesAdapter;


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(saveInstanceState);
    notes = new ArrayList<>();
    notes.add(new Note("Some Content here","NOTE 1"));
    notes.add(new Note("Some Content here","NOTE 1"));
    notes.add(new Note("Some Content here","NOTE 1"));
    notes.add(new Note("Some Content here","NOTE 1"));
    notes.add(new Note("Some Content here","NOTE 1"));
    notes.add(new Note("Some Content here","NOTE 1"));
    notes.add(new Note("Some Content here","NOTE 1"));
    notes.add(new Note("Some Content here","NOTE 1"));
    notes.add(new Note("Some Content here","NOTE 1"));
    notes.add(new Note("Some Content here","NOTE 1"));

    notesAdapter = new NotesAdapter(getActivity(),notes);
    setListAdapter(notesAdapter);
    getListView().setDivider(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(),android.R.color.black));
    getListView().setDividerHeight(1);


}

@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    //position of item passed
    Note note = (Note) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),NoteDetailActivity.class);
    //passing info from the item
    intent.putExtra("Title",note.getTitle());
    intent.putExtra("Message",note.getMessage());
    intent.putExtra("NoteID",note.getNoteID());
    startActivity(intent);

}




}
```

And this is my Adapter

```
public class NotesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Note> {

//hold the references of the data
public static class ViewHolder {
    private TextView noteTitle;
    private TextView contentNote;

}



public NotesAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Note> notes) {
    super(context, 0, notes);
}

@Override
//get called for every row item
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    //data for position
    Note note = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        //new object to save view references
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

        //getting the references and store in viewHolder
        viewHolder.noteTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(noteTitle);
        viewHolder.contentNote = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.noteContent);
        //reference holder
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        //if there is a view, get the widget for it, from viewHolder
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    //filling data with according view
    viewHolder.noteTitle.setText(note.getTitle());
    viewHolder.contentNote.setText(note.getMessage());


    //display the data
    return convertView;
}

}
```

And finally the Note class

```
public class Note {


private String title, message;
private long noteID, dateCreated;



public Note(String message, String title) {

    this.message = message;
    this.title = title;
    this.noteID = 0;
    this.dateCreated = 0;
}

public Note( long dateCreated, String message, long noteID, String title) {

    this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    this.message = message;
    this.noteID = noteID;
    this.title = title;
}


public long getDateCreated() {
    return dateCreated;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public long getNoteID() {
    return noteID;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public String toString() {
    return "ID: " + noteID + " Title: " + title + " Message " + message  + " Date ";
}
```

}

And this is my NoteDetail Activity, when i click the item it should start this activity

```
public class NoteDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_detail);
}
}
```

I am not sure why when i click an item/note, doesn't start  the activity? And it is not  giving any error at all, and, the items are rendering as i want.

Comment: did you declare this activity on your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), NoteDetailActivity.class);

Comment: Yea, everything is there

Comment: remove the ` super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);`

Comment: can you post your log also

Comment: Is the method being called? Did you set a breakpoint? You can try to replace `startActivity(intent);` with `getActivity.startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Yea, i  set a breakpoint at the method, and no, is not calling anything. Also i replaced as you suggest, and nothing happen, no error, the method is not called at all.

Comment: You must register 'Listener' for event 'OnItemClick'. EX: 'listview. setOnItemClickListener(ListFragmentMain.this);'

Comment: Register in onCreateView()     getListView().setOnItemClickListener(getActivity());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder,

Why are you using `Note note = (Note) getListAdapter().getItem(position);` in spite of having no `getItem(position)` method implemented in your `adapter` class?

Instead use this, as I think your `note` is getting `null` -

```
Note note = notes.get(position);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are trying to achieve this is quite outdated. You should go ahead with RecyclerView for obvious reasons. I have an app that i developed some times back. It creates/edit notes and you can view them in chronological order. Also on clicking your are taken to note edit activity.

Here: https://github.com/muditpant13/Notebook

Hope it is useful for you. :) Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Find the solution

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Note note = (Note) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),NoteDetailActivity.class);
    //passing info from the item
    intent.putExtra("Title",note.getTitle());
    intent.putExtra("Message",note.getMessage());
    intent.putExtra("NoteID",note.getNoteID());
    startActivity(intent);

}
```